# Angular support for form validation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

Hi there I'm trying to use Angular support for form validation but is not working (but I don't have problems with HTML validation). Can you check my code? Thanks!

```
           <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm" ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : commentForm.newUser.$error.required && !commentForm.newUser.$pristine }"> 
                    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="newCommentCon.newUser" required>
                        <span ng-show="commentForm.newUser.$error.required && !commentForm.newUser.$pristine" class="help-block">Your Name is required.</span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">  
                    <label for="Number of Stars" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number of Stars</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">    
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 3
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="option4"> 4
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio5" value="option5"> 5
                        </label>
                    </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!commentForm.$valid">Submit comment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this

You have to use id of the field instead of model name

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
});
```

```css
.has-error{
    border-color: rgba(229, 30, 23, 0.88);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 1px rgba(229, 103, 23, 0.075) inset, 0 0 2px rgba(199, 7, 0, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

<form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm" ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="newCommentCon.newUser" required ng-class="{ 'has-error' : commentForm.Name.$error.required && !commentForm.Name.$pristine }">
                        <span ng-show="commentForm.Name.$error.required && !commentForm.Name.$pristine" class="help-block">Your Name is required.</span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">  
                    <label for="Number of Stars" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number of Stars</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">    
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 3
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="option4"> 4
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio5" value="option5"> 5
                        </label>
                    </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!commentForm.$valid">Submit comment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
            </form>
  </div>
```

[image: Workking screen shot]

Comment: Your are cool! It worked! Tell me, what about a red border when the field name is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the code a bit, 
whatever you use to add ng-class should use the name attribute of form, and name attribute of the input type.

for example:

```
  ng-class="{'has-error':commentForm.newUser. ..}"
```

here commentForm will be the value of name of form, and newUser is the value of name of the input type you are trying to validate.

hope this was the issue.
have changed the code, try this

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm" ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : commentForm.newUser.$error.required && !commentForm.newUser.$pristine }"> 
                <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="newUser" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="newCommentCon.newUser" required>
                    <span ng-show="commentForm.newUser.$error.required && !commentForm.newUser.$pristine" class="help-block">Your Name is required.</span> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">  
                <label for="Number of Stars" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number of Stars</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">    
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                          <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 3
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="option4"> 4
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio5" value="option5"> 5
                    </label>
                </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!commentForm.$valid">Submit comment</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```